# List index out of bound(3) in delphi

Tags: delphi

I recently started to code in delphi, and was working with TListBox.
In this example i wanted to transfer the selected list of items from ListBox1 to ListBox2 on a button click and delete those selected item from ListBox1.
This is the code that i wrote.

```
 procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var I:Integer;
begin

   for I := 0 to ListBox1.GetCount-1 do
   begin
     if ListBox1.Selected[I]=true then
     begin
         ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items[I]);

         ListBox1.Items.Delete(I);
     end;
   end;
```

Im pretty sure that the code logic is right but im getting this error

```
List index out of bound(3)
```

Can someone please explain more about this error and help me resolve it. Thank you

Comment: You are deleting items from ListBox1 while you are looping through ListBox1, so you are invalidating the loop counter and it will eventually go out of bounds.

Comment: Also, just for future reference, you don't call `GetCount` on a ListBox or ComboBox. It has a `Count` property which you should use instead. So your outer loop should use `ListBox1.Count - 1`.